# Pass ContactId to Apex from js controller in LWC

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, customer-community

I'm trying to pass the contactid for a community user in LWC but however it shows as null in apex, not sure what I'm missing here:

Also  error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
[records is not defined]
```

**JS Controller**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track} from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getRecordRelatedToContact from '@salesforce/apex/ContactRecordController.getRecordRelatedToContact';

import USER_ID from "@salesforce/user/Id";
import CONTACT_ID from "@salesforce/schema/User.ContactId";

export default class LWCControllerContactRecord extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: USER_ID, fields: [CONTACT_ID] })
    user;

    @track records;

      get contactId() {
          return getFieldValue(this.user.data, CONTACT_ID);
      }

@wire(getRecordRelatedToContact, {conId: '$contactId'}) 
        WireRecords({error, data}){
        if(data){
            this.records = data;
            this.error = undefined;
            console.log(records);
        }else{
            this.error = error;
            this.records = undefined;
        }
    }

}
```

***Apex controller**

```
public with sharing class ContactRecordController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List<Contact_Child__c> getRecordRelatedToContact(String conId) {
            system.debug('conId >> ' + conId);
            
            List<Contact_Child__c> cc = [SELECT Id, Contact__c from Contact_Child__c where Contact__c = :conId];
            system.debug('@@@'+cc);
            return cc;
            
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are using [getFieldValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_get_field_value) properly.

```
getFieldValue('record;, 'field_api_name');
```

you seem to be passing in the recordId instead of the field's api name.

I dont understand why you are not passing the CONTACT_ID to your apex invokation though, since this is what you seem to be trying to do.

.